# Unable to access kubernetes external service locally through browser

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubectl, minikube

**angular.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: angular-deployment
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: angular
spec:
  replicas: 3
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app.kubernetes.io/name: angular
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app.kubernetes.io/name: angular    
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: angular
        image: mannu23/angular_app:v1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 30000
        resources:
            limits:
              memory: 200Mi
            requests:
              cpu: 100m
              memory: 200Mi
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: angular-service
spec:
  type: NodePort
  selector:
    app.kubernetes.io/name: angular
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 30000
      targetPort: 30010
```

In browser, I am hitting http://192.168.49.2:32332,but unable to open my application.Please someone help to figure out the issue.To check the command that i performed,please click on below "terminal output image".

[Terminal output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lgDIB.png)

Comment: explain locally.

Where the kubernetes run and from where are you trying the service ?

Comment: I am using docker and minikube and trying to open  my angular application in browser.Please refer " Terminal output image" for more details.

Comment: try  http://localhost:32332.

also you may try ````http://angular-service:32332````

or ````http://angular-service.svc.cluster.local:32332````

Comment: Hi Christos,I tried the above urls , but it's not working .By the way thanks for your feedback

Answer (score 0):

You are exposing it on port 30000 and trying to access some other port.
Try this: `http://192.168.49.2:30000`

Comment: Hi KodeMagician , I did but issue still persist. Btw thanks for your suggestion